# Laravel 5.1 - Relationships on model with null values

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I'm having problem with Relationships on model with null values on Laravel 5.1.

I Have 2 Tables Tasks and Users. In Tasks i have the column id_requester and id_responsible.

I want to show all tasks, i always have a requester, but some times i don't have a responsible yet.

So the id_responsible is null in this cases.

My Model is:

```
 protected $table = 'tasks';

 protected $fillable = array(
            'id_requester',
            'id_responsible',
        );

public function requester()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('app\User', 'id', 'id_requester');
    }

public function responsible()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('app\User', 'id', 'id_responsible');
    }
```

The query in my controller is:

```
$tasks = Tasks::get();
```

I'm try to show in view like this:

```
<table>
...
@foreach($tasks as $task)
   <td>{{ $task->requester->name }}</td>

   <td>{{ $task->responsible->name }}</td>
@endforeach
...
</table>
```

The problem is that when i try access the page I get an error 'Trying to get property of non-object'.

I already test and this is only when i have a id_responsible = Null.

How can i fix this to show all registers?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, lets talk about displaying conditional data.

From the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data

> Sometimes you may wish to echo a variable, but you aren't sure if the variable has been set. We can express this in verbose PHP code like so:
>
> `{{ isset($name) ? $name : 'Default' }}`
>
> However, instead of writing a ternary statement, Blade provides you with the following convenient short-cut:
>
> `{{ $name or 'Default' }}`
>
> In this example, if the $name variable exists, its value will be displayed. However, if it does not exist, the word Default will be displayed.

In other words, you should be able to do this:

```
<td>{{ $task->requester->name or 'No requester' }}</td>

<td>{{ $task->responsible->name or 'Nobody responsible.' }}</td>
```

This will display the appropriate data only if it exists. If not, it will display either "Nobody responsible" or "No requester".

However, if your question is how to get tasks that only have someone responsible, you can change the query to use the [`has`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) method:

```
$tasks = Tasks::has('responsible')->get();
```

This will only retrieve tasks that has a "responsible" person already assigned so that you don't have to worry about null values.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
@foreach($tasks as $task)
   <td>{{ $task->requester->name }}</td>

   <td>{{ $task->responsible->name }}</td>
@endforeach
```

you should use:

```
@foreach($tasks as $task)
   <td>{{ $task->requester ? $task->requester->name : 'unknown' }}</td>

   <td>{{ $task->responsible ? $task->responsible->name : 'unknown' }}</td>
@endforeach
```

This is because both `$task->requester` and `$task->responsible` might be null (there is no related record) so you cannot use name property (`->name`) on `null`